# How to read specific Key from JSON file with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to read a Json file with some passwords but them are stored into Key-Value pattern as below:

```
{
    "id":  "a8cc4184-3844-4605-8e35-ea479ae1094e",
    "name":  "Test Credentials and Secrets",
    "values":  [
                   {
                       "key":  "apassword",
                       "value":  "mypassword",
                       "enabled":  true
                   },
                   {
                       "key":  "tpassword",
                       "value":  "my other password",
                       "enabled":  true
                   },
               ],
    "exported_using":  "Postman/7.34.0"
}
```

How can I get any specific value with PowerShell? **tpassword** value for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `ConvertFrom-Json` to turn it into an Object so you can then access the properties easily with PowerShell.

I saved the json above to `C:\temp\json.json` and then the following got me the tpassword value:

```
$json = Get-Content C:\temp\json.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.values | Where-Object key -eq 'tpassword' | Select-Object Value
```

[image: PowerShell terminal showing results]

Comment: Hey, your console looks cool! Is this a special app or an extension of the regular pwsh console?

Comment: It's Windows terminal with an oh my posh prompt (https://ohmyposh.dev/).

Comment: I've copied this code, and `Write-Host $json` shows the JSON data block, but `Write-Host $json.values`  outputs a blank line -- why?

Comment: I have posted a [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74700877/20571)