# Cannot read specific key from JSON file with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a large JSON file (vehicle data) from which I want to read 1 specific value (vehicle identification number, for example). So, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71502074/20571), I have this code with debug output:

```
$json = Get-Content $responsefilepath | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $json
Write-Host $json.values | Where-Object key -eq "coc_VIN"
```

1. The first line puts my inputs file into an object;
2. the second line outputs the content of my file:
   [image]
3. the third line *should* provide the value `YV1DZ8256D2390218`, **but it's just blank.**
4. On the PS command line, this provides a nice table of all values:
   `Get-Content .\data\02-returned\sample.json | ConvertFrom-Json`
   [image]
5. I would extend that command to filter on the desired key:
   `Get-Content .\data\02-returned\sample.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object key -eq "coc_VIN"`
   and again, that returns a blank line. **Why?**

Input file:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

`Where-Object key` presumes that there is a key/value pair where the name of the key is literally `key`. My data does not have that, so that's why it does not work.

Instead, I can use the dot notation to select the value of the key named "coc_VIN":

```
$json = Get-Content $responsefilepath | ConvertFrom-Json
$myvalue = $json.coc_VIN
```

...and that works!

Comment: Please consider marking this as the solution to the question (I think you have to wait 24 hours for checking your own answers as solutions).